# How to retrieve YouTube video id of videos from a channel (YouTube)

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-channels, android-youtube-api

I am working in an android app which shows videos from a YouTube Channel.

I have the channel id and all other stuffs. But I need the **video id** to show the video in YouTube Player.

```
***eg. player.cueVideo("nCgQDjiotG0");***
```

When I go through the developer site again and again, I got this one `-https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/videos?part=id&chart=mostPopular&key={YOUR_API_KEY}`

It is working perfectly returning the correct Video id to play. But I can't done it with my Channel id (There is no option for passing channel ID as parameter).

The only one `url` which accept the `channel ID` and returns snippet is this one -

```
https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/search?part=snippet&channelId=UCxUtHtpGzd0bA5rYRY7h4VQ&q=PIVideoLibrary&type=channel&key={YOUR_API_KEY}
```

But the id it returning is not compatible with the above method. When I run it in the device it shows `"Invalid Request"` Here is screen shot which is the response of the above search request.[image: The Screen shot]

**So this is my question.**

> How can we get video id of a video from a YouTube channel to show that
>   vedio in a youtube player integrated in the android app using YouTube
>   api v3

**Thank You.**

Comment: Did you get you solution i have something similar issue

Comment: ya, I added the answer. :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya I found it.

Go to youtube developer, https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/activities/list . 
You can find a "TRY IT" field at middle of the page, fill the fields, you have to enter "**contentDetails** in the 'part' field to obtain video id. Then enter your channel id in the respective field. Execute the query, you can find the video id in the XML result. [image]